# Почему в richTextBox текст выводится не с первой строки, а со второй?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Почему в richTextBox текст выводится не с первой строки, а со второй?

```
rTB_Result.Text += Environment.NewLine;
rTB_Result.Text += Environment.NewLine + "---";
```

Вроде должно быть так: первая строка пустая, а вторая "---".
а у меня выводится: первая строка пустая, вторая пустая, третья "---".

Comment: Ну там ведь изначально лежит какая-то строка, пусть даже пустая `""`, вы добавляете перевод строки - их становится 2 и т. д.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` - это не просто новая строка, а символ (или набор символов) перевода строки, т.е. строк всегда на одну больше чем переводов строк

Comment: Вы добавляете два перевода строки, понятно, что каждый из них даёт вам пустую строку.

Comment: @Андрей, я вывожу текст по циклу и первый перевод строки нужен, чтобы текст был более читабелен. Т.е. от первой пустой строки никак не избавиться?

Comment: А переделать нельзя, чтобы перевод строки добавлялся не перед, а после нового сообщения? Обычно так делается

Comment: @Андрей, попробую, сложно отловить, какая строка будет последней.

Comment: @Nataka: Вы ж программист! Ну так отлавливайте случай, когда это первая строка, а не когда последняя.